# Sports tipping website tutorial or reference

Tags: php, html, css, reactjs, content-management-system

G,day!

I've recently finished a full stack development course and i'm ready to get my hands dirty on a project that I've been wanting to do for a long time now

Basically want to create a Soccer tipping website with CMS in which I want the admin to be able to create the following

- Create multiple Leagues eg (English premier league, la liga etc)
- Create multiple Division eg (Premier league, Championship etc)
- Create multiple Teams eg( Manchester City, Liverpool etc)
- Create Multiple Rounds eg (Round 01, Round 02 etc)
- Create Multiple Fixtures eg( Team 01 vs Team 02 @ Date @ time)

In the frontend user can do the following

- Create an account
- Join a league & division
- Predict the result of a fixture
- Collect point for a correct prediction
- Go into a leaderboard with other users

The admin can also mark the results correct or wrong which will updates users points and order the leaderboard once results are inputted by the admin

All im really asking is where can i find a tutorial or similar in which i can start with and build upon. Can be any type of code base like react or others, if anyone has any references or has seen a course that uses a similar model that i can modify that would be awesome!

Just need a point in the right direction!

Cheers!

Comment: There is no one tutorial which will cover all of your requirements.

Comment: If you don't shoot you don't score right? :)

Comment: Yeah, but you just air-balled ;-)

Comment: _“All im really asking is where can i find a tutorial or similar”_ - that kind of question is considered off-topic here to begin with, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tutorials. But you can start from choosing tech stack for your project and then find the corresponding tutorials. For example, if you decide to use Python as a backend language and Flask framework you can find a lot of tutorials that would allow you to build the core application (with accounts, registration etc.)

The next step would be to decompose your whole task into small pieces and implement them one-by-one. If you know already React it wouldn't be any problem for you.